# LIGO's upper-bound on the Michelson-Morley null result?

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, interferometry, ligo, aether

[LIGO is essentially a Michelson-Morley experiment.](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/ligos-ifo?highlight=michelson) What is its measured upper-bound on the fringe shift?

The most recent Michel-Morley experiment "[Michelson–Morley experiment#Subsequent experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment#Subsequent_experiments)" mentions is [Joos (1930)](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/4U3R9UPS/Joos%20-%201930%20-%20Die%20Jenaer%20Wiederholung%20des%20Michelsonversuchs.pdf) ([DeepL English translation](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/S7NZIVEB/Joos%20-%201930%20-%20Die%20Jenaer%20Wiederholung%20des%20Michelsonversuchs_eng.txt)), who measured a fringe shift $≤ \frac{1}{1000}$, corresponding to $< 1.5 \text{ km/s}$ on $V_\mathrm{ether}$.

Comment: Probably rather poor because you can’t rotate the LIGO apparatus to change the incoming direction of an “ether wind”. There would be a daily modulation as the Earth rotates, but it’s probably hard to distinguish that from backgrounds.